# Shannon expansion in a boolean function

Tags: boolean, boolean-logic, boolean-expression

According to this page in Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boole%27s_expansion_theorem) The Shannon expansion or decomposition theorem, also known as Boole's expansion theorem is an identity that allows the expansion of any logic function to broken down into parts. in other word:

```
F = X . F (X = 1) + X' . F (X = 0)
```

so I tried to implement this logic in a simple C++ code and it didn't work, here is what I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#define f(x,y,z) (((x) & (y)) | ((x) & (z)))
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    unsigned int a = 0x215f8;
    unsigned int b = 0x77012;
    unsigned int c = 0x33548;

    cout << f(a,b,c) << endl;
    cout << (((~a) & f(0,b,c)) | ((a) & f(1,b,c))) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

what I'm I missing?

**EDIT**:

the output of the program is:

```
136536

0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the mistake I was doing is that I was using Shannon expansion theorem in it's fondamental form, the shannon expansion should work on the set B={0,1} so when we try to extend this idea to integers we should consider all aspects of that extension, the shannon expasion in the boolean space is `f(a,b,c) = a'.f(0,b,c) + a.f(1,b,c)` my mistake is that I used that exact form while I should instead use `f(a,b,c) = a'.f(0,b,c) + a.f(MAX_UNSIGNED_INT,b,c)` which will put a constant with all 1's in it, this works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>
#define f(x,y,z) (((x) & (y)) | ((x) & (z)))
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    unsigned int a = 0x215f8;
    unsigned int b = 0x77012;
    unsigned int c = 0x33548;

    cout << f(a,b,c) << endl;
    cout << (((~a) & f(0,b,c)) | ((a) & f(UINT_MAX,b,c))) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should mark this as the answer.  Your explanation is easy to follow.

Comment: @Bill I will be able to after 24h, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to use the operators: `||` `&&`?  If so the following code seems to work:

```
#include <iostream>
#define f(x,y,z) (((x) && (y)) || ((x) && (z)))
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    unsigned int a = 0x215f8;
    unsigned int b = 0x77012;
    unsigned int c = 0x33548;

    cout << f(a,b,c) << endl;
    cout << (((~a) && f(0,b,c)) || ((a) && f(1,b,c))) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output is 1.

Comment: I see, so why isn't it working on boolean operators?

Comment: It should normaly work on both bitwise and logical operators isn't it?

Comment: Given a and b above, what do you want for `cout << (a & b) << endl;` ?  1 or 135184?  Isn't Shannon's expansion only for boolean operators, such as AND, NOR, OR, NOT etc.?

Comment: & should give 135184. although shannon expansion works on the set B={0,1} that idea can be extended to integers since & works on bit by bit on each integer